# iOS : AES Encryption

Tags: android, ios, base64, aes, commoncrypto

I am getting wrong encryption in iOS, android is work perfectly, here is both code.

Here is the Android AES Encryption Code.

```
private final String characterEncoding = "UTF-8";
private final String cipherTransformation = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
private final String aesEncryptionAlgorithm = "AES";
private final String key="83jdkey3jdcmQNAieNanAN==";
private final String keyPass="testhello";
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.hello.com/";
private final String URL = "http://hello/secure.asmx";

boolean flag = false;

public byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte [] initialVector) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException
{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpecy = new SecretKeySpec(key, aesEncryptionAlgorithm);
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initialVector);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpecy, ivParameterSpec);
    cipherText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
    return cipherText;
}

public byte[] encrypt(byte[] plainText, byte[] key, byte [] initialVector) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, aesEncryptionAlgorithm);
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initialVector);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
    plainText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
    return plainText;
}

private byte[] getKeyBytes(String key) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    byte[] keyBytes= new byte[16];
    byte[] parameterKeyBytes= key.getBytes(characterEncoding);
    System.arraycopy(parameterKeyBytes, 0, keyBytes, 0, Math.min(parameterKeyBytes.length, keyBytes.length));
    return keyBytes;
}

public String encrypt(String plainText) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
{
    byte[] plainTextbytes = plainText.getBytes(characterEncoding);
    byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(key);
    return Base64.encodeToString(encrypt(plainTextbytes,keyBytes, keyBytes), Base64.DEFAULT);
}

public String decrypt(String encryptedText) throws KeyException, GeneralSecurityException, GeneralSecurityException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException
{
    byte[] cipheredBytes = Base64.decode(encryptedText, Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(key);
    return new String(decrypt(cipheredBytes, keyBytes, keyBytes), characterEncoding);
}
```

And here is i am using for iOS encryption.

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>

@implementation NSData (AES256)

- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                     keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                     NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                     [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                     buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                     &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}

- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                     keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                     NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                     [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                     buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                     &numBytesDecrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}

@end
```

http://pastie.org/426530#7,9-12,15-17,21-26

Can you please check how both encryption are different.

Comment: what is your problem??

Comment: Getting different encryption string in iOS..

Comment: checkout [this one](https://github.com/Pakhee/Cross-platform-AES-encryption) . it works perfectly for andoid,ios,c#. and it is performing in similar way for all platforms.

Comment: I have already check this link before, but my issue is different in my case android is working condition, i just need to same work in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS code is using AES256 and requires a 256-bit (32-byte) key, you have a 128-bit (16-byte) key so it will not work.

Just get all the input correct and you will get the same result. concentrate on just the encryption, and use hex-dumps to verify that data and inputs/outputs. The options need to be identical and lengths exactly correct. Once the encryption is working add the Base64 wrapper and other goodies.

If you then need more help post the iOS code along with the hex-dumps as above.

Comment: Then how can i do this ?